# Only download Sentinel-1A Data Python Sentinelsat

Tags: python, sentinelsat

I use Sentinelsat to download Sentinel-1 Data. What should I edit in the query search, that Sentinelsat only downloads Sentinel-1A data? The API query with the searching parameters looks like this:

```
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date=('20210701', '20210712'),
                     platformname='Sentinel-1',
                     producttype='GRD',
                     limit=4
                     )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a filter on the filename which starts with either `"S1A"` or `"S1B"`. The * Operator refers to any sequence of zero or more characters, so try this:

```
products = api.query(footprint,
                     date=('20210701', '20210712'),
                     platformname='Sentinel-1',
                     producttype='GRD',
                     limit=4,
                     filename="S1A*"
                     )
```

More information can be found [here](https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/do/view/SciHubUserGuide/FullTextSearch?redirectedfrom=SciHubUserGuide.3FullTextSearch) as well.